# Not able to parse JSON file from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I have following code :

```
var mydata=null;
    $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://servername:8080/Project/data.json?callback=?",
            success : function(data) {
            mydata=data;
            }
```

When i tried above code i was not able to get JSON file but when i kept json file in local folder, i was able to run the code with local url....

Is anything i am missing here?

Comment: do that: 1. check the file permission. 2. hit the url on browser and check it show the result or not.

Comment: You can't make an AJAX call to a server other than where the JavaScript file was served from. You'll need to use [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing] via a proxy or enable it on your server.

Comment: @ MIss poo. I am able to get the file through url

Comment: does trying this URL **http://servername:8080/Project/data.json** in the browser working?

Comment: @ Fizer Khan ... yeswhen i hit the url i get the file